# Parsing data to the view using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql

This is my function. I am trying to parse data to the view but i have failed to initialize the arrays to some variables

```
function blogs()
{
   $this->load->model('blog/Den_model');
   $this->load->model('Den_model');      

   $da['qry']=$this->Den_model->get_last_ten_entries();
   $data['title']='Dennis';         
   $data['heading']=$da;
   $this->load->view('blogview',$data); 
}
```

---

this is the view code

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1><?php echo($heading);  ?></h1>    
   <h2>To DO list</h2>
<h3>
<?php
  //foreach($other as $hot)
{
   // echo($hot.'<br/>');
}

 ?>
</h3>
```

When i out put it using print_r in the view mode this is what i get
 `Array ( [qry] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [title] => First Blog [content] => This is the First Blog [time] => 2013-12-18 00:00:00 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [title] => Second Blog [content] => this is the second blog [time] => 2013-12-17 00:00:00 ) ) )`

and when i use echo this is what i get A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: views/blogview.php

Line Number: 6

Array

To DO list

Comment: please add view code and debug $data array in controller

Comment: please provide additional code and more details about the error you are having

Comment: i have added  the view code

Comment: it looks like that you are trying to populate an array in heading, correct me if im wrong

Comment: i was trying to test weather i receive the data from the database but now i wanted to display it to the interface in an organised way but i have failed to extract it so that it is not displayed in array way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function blogs()
      {
        $this->load->model('blog/Den_model');
      $this->load->model('Den_model');
 //this gets loads the class for Den_model and function get_last_ten_entries()

      $data['qry']=$this->Den_model->get_last_ten_entries();
      $data['title']='Dennis';

                 $this->load->view('blogview',$data); 
      }
```

and this is what i did for the View

```
 foreach($qry as $row)
{

    //prints data in the array
    print_r($row->title.' - '.$row->content.' - '.$row->time.'<br/>');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Controller function is:

```
  function blogs()
  {
    $this->load->model('blog/Den_model');
    $this->load->model('Den_model');
    $data['qry']=$this->Den_model->get_last_ten_entries();
    $data['title']='Dennis';
    $this->load->vars($data);
   $this->load->view('blogview',$data); 
  }
```

The model function is:

```
function get_last_ten_entries()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('blog_db', 10);
    return $query->result();
}
```

and in VIEW

you can use

```
foreach($heading as $row) {
  echo $row->"database column name";
}
```

Hope it will help you.
Thankyou